# Testing when an object is being cast with Mockito leads to ClassCastException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test a method with Mockito and am getting the following error:
"java.lang.ClassCastException: MessageContext$MockitoMock incompatible with SOAPMessageContext"

This the relevant fragment of my code to be tested:

```
public static String returnMessage(MessageContext ctx){
try{
SOAPMessageContext mc = (SOAPMessageContext) ctx;
if(mc != null){
...
}
}
}
```

mc is null and it does not go past this point when I try to debug my test.

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void testReturnMessage(){

MessageContext mockMc = mock(MessageContext.class);
SOAPMessageContext mockSMc = (SOAPMessageContext)mock(MessageContext.class);

assertNotNull(MyClass.returnMessage(mockMc);
}
```

From what I understand you cannot cast a mock. But how do I get around this issue? How can I test something like this?

Comment: please provide the entire error message. We have no idea of knowing what cast fails.

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: Why you take as `returnMessage` the `mockMc` and not `mockSMc`?

Comment: I wanted to use that in case I cannot make it work like this.

Comment: how does the errormessage not explain your problem?

Comment: It does. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: At the very least you'll have to `mock(SOAPMessageContext.class)` if you want to cast to `SOAPMessageContext`... Also, the parameter in your (non-test) method is `ctx` but you're casting `context`, is that a copy-paste issue? Also, you say "mc is null" - but that wouldn't cause a `ClassCastException` - again, very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
MessageContext mockMc = mock(SOAPMessageContext.class);
```

or

```
@Mock(extraInterfaces = {SOAPMessageContext.class})
MessageContext mockMc;
```

Comment: The first one has fixed part of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm how is it different from my answer?

Comment: @daniu it's mock(SOAPMessageContext.class) instead of MessageContext.class for mockMc. This is what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the correct class.

```
@Test
public void testReturnMessage(){
MessageContext mockMc = mock(MessageContext.class);
  SOAPMessageContext mockSMc = mock(SOAPMessageContext.class);

  assertNotNull(MyClass.returnMessage(mockMc));
}
```

This works fine.

If your question is how to check if you have the correct class, you can't check for null, but need to use `instanceof` or catch the `ClassCastException` you're observing.

```
try {
  SOAPMessageContext mc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
} catch (ClassCastException x) { 
  // could not be cast
}
```

or

```
if (context instanceof SOAPMessageContext) {
  SOAPMessageContext mc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
} else {
  // cannot be cast
}
```

In the latest Java versions, this can be done like this

```
if (context instanceof SOAPMessageContext mc) {
  // mc now a SOAPMessageContext, no explicit cast necessary
} else {
  // cannot be cast
}
```

EDIT:
With "this works fine" above, I mean that this mcve test succeeds.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class MockCastTest {
  SomeClass sut = new SomeClass();

  @Test
  public void testCast() {
    ChildClass child = mock(ChildClass.class);
    ChildClass castChild = sut.cast(child);
    assertNotNull(castChild);
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  public ChildClass cast(ParentClass parent) {
    return (ChildClass) parent;
  }

}
class ParentClass {}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}
```

Comment: I've tried what you wrote in the test. It ends up being null for me. I am catching the exception in my code. I just don't know how to test the code - specifically the part with the casting to SOAPMessageContext.

Comment: @CarinaTheBookworm if it's `null`, there must be another issue. I added a fully contained test to my answer - the test successfully runs on my end.